# Advanced PDB Graphics Error using VS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, directx, pdb-files

[image]

So here is the output I have been trying to get past. I recently installed VS12 on a new PC. First I was unable to load any PDB files but this was resolved by loading in from the Microsoft Symbol Servers. The last 4, which I have concluded were ATI graphics dll's coming from my graphics driver still did not want to load. This resulted in a crash on the DX flag - D3DLOCK_DISCARD while trying to lock a dynamic rect. My first thought was an out of date driver so after I updated the driver and that failed I am left with no answers. I was unable to find any useful information on Google and nothing here relating specifically to this problem. Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated and any more info required to solve the problem, please ask and I will be happy to provide.

Comment: There's no problem with the PDB warnings, they are just saying that you'll get no debugging symbols for those libraries. The error message is quite clear - you can only use `D3DLOCK_DISCARD` with a dynamic texture. If you post some source code, we can help further but I'm guessing that you carry on after the error and are trying to use a `NULL` pointer. Then you get the access violation.

Comment: Possible driver problem or non-compliant gfx card - if you google for `D3DLOCK_DISCARD` you'll find similar issues.